# Modify libraryDependcies inside of SBT

Tags: sbt

I use SBT / Console as a prototyping tool and therefore don't want to start with a pre-defined build.sbt file.

What I want to do is to run the `sbt` tool and then modify the libraryDependencies setting. then run `console` and go and use my newly imported library. If I need something more. I can exit the console and import more stuff and then come back in the console.

is this possible? or should I always start with a predefined build.sbt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set libraryDependencies += group % art % version`

I understand ammonite is good at this as well